# indexOf function meet php

Tags: javascript, jquery

What `indexOf` for? I just added it to PHP code and changed my filename (from index.html to homepage.php) and also changed `<a href="index.html" >` to `<a href="?r=site/index">` and the class `active` wont work then.

What is the reason that trigger this error?

**HTML**

```
<nav class="main-navi">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.html" >
                Home
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="portfolio.html">
                Portfolio
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.html">
                About
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="service.html">
                services
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="blog.html">
                Blog
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.html">
                contacts
                <span class="dot"></span>
                <span class="corner"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <em id="showHideMenu" class="show-hide-menu fa fa-bars" href="#"></em>
</nav>
```

**JS**

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;
$('.main-navi ul li a').each(function () {
    var status = loc.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1;
    $(this).toggleClass('active', status);
});
```

Comment: Still index.html in HTML?

Comment: When still only html i use index.html but when  i change to php i change the a href

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.pathname` contains only path part of the URL. Use `window.location.href` to search within the full URL:

```
var loc = window.location.href;
....
```

However note that such comparison may fail if for example there are more parameters in the URL.